# Flatpickr loading as AM time instead of PM time

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, razor, flatpickr

Having an issue with the Flatpickr. I am utilizing the Date and Time feature of Flatpickr. It works perfect till I try to load and time that is PM time, It will load the PM time as AM always. For example, in my database I have a dateTime stored as 2021-03-09 21:00:00.000 but it will load into the application as 9:00 am instead of 9:00 pm. I searched through the Flatpickr documentation and unable to find any others experiencing this issue.

I would also be fine with a solution to have the time show as military. Even though I have it set as Military in my html razor, it still loads as AM.

```
<div class="col-sm-3 form-group" id="datetimepicker1">
    @Html.Label("Est Completion")
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CaseMaster.DateEstCompletion, new { @Id = "EstCompletion", @class = "form-control col-sm", @placeholder = "Est Completion", @data_toggle = "flatpickr", @data_enable_time = "true", @time_24hr = "true",  @data_date_format = "m/d/Y H:i"})
</div>
```

Thank you for your time

Comment: I was able to get this working by adding in the seconds into the formatting string data_date_format = "m-d-Y G:i:S K"

https://flatpickr.js.org/formatting/

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working by adding in the seconds into the formatting string data_date_format = "m-d-Y G:i:S K" flatpickr.js.org/formatting